# Capturing images from webcam using avicap32 in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, webcam

I am using Delphi 7 in my project.

The aim of the project is to capture images from a webcam. The program seems to detect the webcam, and shows a window in which I can select the desired webcam, but the screen is simply black, and does not show any thing.

The code is the following:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics,
  Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Buttons;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    SaveDialog1: TSaveDialog;
    Button3: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    hWndC : THandle;
    CapturingAVI : bool;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const WM_CAP_START                  = WM_USER;
const WM_CAP_STOP                   = WM_CAP_START + 68;
const WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT         = WM_CAP_START + 10;
const WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT      = WM_CAP_START + 11;
const WM_CAP_SAVEDIB                = WM_CAP_START + 25;
const WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME             = WM_CAP_START + 60;
const WM_CAP_SEQUENCE               = WM_CAP_START + 62;
const WM_CAP_FILE_SET_CAPTURE_FILEA = WM_CAP_START + 20;

Function capCreateCapt(dwStyle : longint; x : integer; y : integer; nWidth : integer;nHeight : integer;ParentWin  : HWND;  nId : integer): HWND; STDCALL EXTERNAL 'AVICAP32.DLL';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CapturingAVI := false;
  hWndC := 0;
  SaveDialog1.Options := [ofHideReadOnly, ofNoChangeDir, ofPathMustExist]
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  hWndC := capCreateCaptureWindowA('My Own Capture Window', WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, Panel1.Left, Panel1.Top, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height, Form1.Handle, 0);
  if hWndC <> 0 then
    SendMessage(hWndC, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, 0, 0 );
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if hWndC <> 0 then begin
    SendMessage(hWndC, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);
    hWndC := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if hWndC <> 0 then
    SendMessage(hWndC, WM_CAP_START, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendMessage(hWndC, WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME, 0, 0);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of `capCreateCaptureWindowA()` is wrong, and you are passing the wrong parameter values to it if you want the webcam display to appear inside the `TPanel`.

Try this instead:

```
function capCreateCaptureWindowA(const lpszWindowName : PAnsiChar; dwStyle : DWORD; x : integer; y : integer; nWidth : integer; nHeight : integer; hwwndParent : HWND; nId : integer): HWND; stdcall; external 'AVICAP32.DLL';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  hWndC := capCreateCaptureWindowA('My Own Capture Window', WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height, Panel1.Handle, 0);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Here is the actual function declaration:

Comment: @MadaniAithellal regardless of declaration, you are still passing parameters to make the capture window be a child of the Form window instead of the Panel window, and occupy the same rectangle as the Panel, but that doesn't guarantee proper z-ordering, the Panel may cover the capture window. Instead, make the Panel be the parent window so the capture window appears inside of it. Otherwise, there is no point in having the Panel at all.

Comment: I tried to replace the form1.hadle with pannel1.handle unfortunately it was the same: the pannel is black.

Comment: function capCreateCaptureWindowA(lpszWindowName : PCHAR;
                                 dwStyle : longint;
                                 x : integer;
                                 y : integer;
                                 nWidth : integer;
                                 nHeight : integer;
                                 ParentWin  : HWND;
                                 nId : integer): HWND;
                                 STDCALL EXTERNAL 'AVICAP32.DLL';

Comment: The *correct* declaration is in my answer. In any case, after you create the capture window, you are not automatically capturing any still images or streaming video for it to display, so of course it is going to be black initially. `WM_CAP_START` is not an actual capture window message, it just denotes the starting range for capture messages. It does nothing if you send it as-is to the capture window. `WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME` works just fine, though. I tested the code in my answer. But, to capture the image data so you can do something with it, you will need to use `WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_FRAME`.

Comment: I used Grabframe in button4 but when i press it no this is displayed on panel1

Comment: Works fine for me, using the code I posted. Check your webcam is actually working.  It did take me a few tries for my computer to turn on my webcam, but then it worked fine. Probably the driver wasn't loaded/activated yet.

Comment: May be the function declaration is wrong i will try and give you feedback thanks a lot

Comment: Hi I used the function declaration you suggested and the thing is the same.Please can you post your complete code so i can test and see where is the problem with me. An other thing is : I am working on windows 7 64 bits.

Comment: @MadaniAithellal use the complete code that you posted in your question, replacing the 2 pieces that I posted in my answer. That is all I did, and it works fine for me (once the computer initialized the webcam - try running the webcam's own capture software first, if you have it installed). And I am also using Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Is it necessary to register the avicap32 dll?

Comment: @MadaniAithellal no

Comment: Hi I have a problem with the embarked webcam of my pc this is the reason of the black screen.  but i connected a new one which i tried with an other software. But the same thing is happening: black screen even if we select the new webcam's driver.

Comment: Hi the cap_driver_connect message is allways zero i think this means that the driver is not connected.

Comment: Any idea about why the WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT. Is not working ??